# Python 2.7 findall() function to exclude finding for regular expression

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to write regular expression to find specific data within HTML.
For example I have

```
'Leicester City'
'Tottenham Hotspur'
'Arsenal FC'
'Manchester City'
'Manchester United'
'Southampton FC'
'West Ham United'
'Liverpool FC'
'Chelsea FC'
'Stoke City'
'Swansea City'
'Everton FC'
'Watford FC'
'Crystal Palace'
'West Bromwich Albion'
'AFC Bournemouth'
'Sunderland AFC'
'Newcastle United'
'Norwich City'
'Aston Villa'
'Channel Boleyn emotion'
'Channel Boleyn emotion'
```

But I don't want to include `'Channel Boleyn emotion'`, how can I excluded `'emotion'` string?

Here is the URL http://www.worldfootball.net/schedule/eng-premier-league-2015-2016-spieltag/37/

```
import urllib2
from re import findall
from urllib import urlopen

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.worldfootball.net/schedule/eng-premier-league-2015-2016-spieltag/37/")
html_bytes = response.read()
html = html_bytes.decode('utf-8')
ranking= findall('[e]="(\w* ?\w* ?\w*)', html)

print ranking()
```

[e]="(\w* ?\w* ?\w*),

The code doesn't work yet, (I'm newbie) but I just want to get rid of 'Channel Boleyn emotion' so I can go further. Thanks

Comment: `^\w+(?: \w+)*(?!\bemotion)$`...........

Comment: @falsetru edited..

Comment: But that also cuts out `'West Bromwich Albion'` and `'West Ham United'` ... What are the _rules_ for which items should stay and which should go?

Comment: Using regexes to parse HTML is, long term, a losing game because it's not a regular language.  Consider using an HTML parser instead.  For example, Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pattern `title="([^"]*)">\1</a>`. This looks for links that have the same title and text.

```
>>> print findall(r'title="([^"]*)">\1</a>', html)
[u'Norwich City', u'Manchester United', u'AFC Bournemouth', u'West Bromwich Albion', u'Aston Villa', u'Newcastle United', u'Crystal Palace', u'Stoke City', u'Sunderland AFC', u'Chelsea FC', u'West Ham United', u'Swansea City', u'Leicester City', u'Everton FC', u'Tottenham Hotspur', u'Southampton FC', u'Liverpool FC', u'Watford FC', u'Manchester City', u'Arsenal FC', u'Leicester City', u'Leicester City', u'Tottenham Hotspur', u'Tottenham Hotspur', u'Arsenal FC', u'Arsenal FC', u'Manchester City', u'Manchester City', u'Manchester United', u'Manchester United', u'Southampton FC', u'Southampton FC', u'West Ham United', u'West Ham United', u'Liverpool FC', u'Liverpool FC', u'Chelsea FC', u'Chelsea FC', u'Stoke City', u'Stoke City', u'Swansea City', u'Swansea City', u'Everton FC', u'Everton FC', u'Watford FC', u'Watford FC', u'Crystal Palace', u'Crystal Palace', u'West Bromwich Albion', u'West Bromwich Albion', u'AFC Bournemouth', u'AFC Bournemouth', u'Sunderland AFC', u'Sunderland AFC', u'Newcastle United', u'Newcastle United', u'Norwich City', u'Norwich City', u'Aston Villa', u'Aston Villa']
```

Comment: Thank for you help, but still had some problem with displaying only data I want, so I found another website with less html so it works now ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to use negative lookahead assertion.

```
^\w+(?: \w+)*(?<!\bemotion)$
```

`(?!\bemotion)$` asserts that the word `emotion` does not exists at the end.

or

```
^\w+(?: \w+)*(?<!\semotion)$
```

or

```
>>> s = [

'Leicester City',
'Tottenham Hotspur',
'Arsenal FC',
'Manchester City',
'Manchester United',
'Southampton FC',
'West Ham United',
'Liverpool FC',
'Chelsea FC',
'Stoke City',
'Swansea City',
'Everton FC',
'Watford FC',
'Crystal Palace',
'West Bromwich Albion',
'AFC Bournemouth',
'Sunderland AFC',
'Newcastle United',
'Norwich City',
'Aston Villa',
'Channel Boleyn emotion',
'Channel Boleyn emotion']
>>> [i for i in s if i.split()[-1] != 'emotion']
['Leicester City', 'Tottenham Hotspur', 'Arsenal FC', 'Manchester City', 'Manchester United', 'Southampton FC', 'West Ham United', 'Liverpool FC', 'Chelsea FC', 'Stoke City', 'Swansea City', 'Everton FC', 'Watford FC', 'Crystal Palace', 'West Bromwich Albion', 'AFC Bournemouth', 'Sunderland AFC', 'Newcastle United', 'Norwich City', 'Aston Villa']
```

Comment: or `[i for i in s if i.split()[-1] != 'emotion']`

Comment: How your exact data looks like?

Comment: Lookahead doesn't work here. You need a lookbehind. A lookahead followed by `$` is a strange idea!